# Alinhando imagens dentro de Panel Bootstrap

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap-3, panel

Tenho o seguinte `Panel`:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">

        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Header</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">Qual seu gênero ?</div>
                <div class="panel-body" style="background-color:red; text-align:center">
                    <img src="../Icons/man.png" title="Homem" style="cursor:pointer"/>
                    <img src="../Icons/woman.png" title="Mulher" style="cursor:pointer"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

O código acima, monta o `Panel` dessa forma :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de alinhar as duas imagens no centro da tela. No meu arquivo CSS fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
.panel {
    text-align:center;
}

img {
  text-align:center;
}
```

O alinhamento funcionou apenas para a classe `.panel`, e a classe `.img` não teve o mesmo resultado. Como devo fazer para alinhar as imagens também ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente chamar diretamente a class "panel-body" responsável pelas imagens no seu CSS, por exemplo:

```
.panel-body {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Após melhore seu código CSS, não se esqueça de substituir:

```
<div class="panel-body" style="background-color:red; text-align:center">
```

Por:

```
<div class="panel-body">
```

Isso já deve resolver seu problema. :)